# Schedule cron job every four hours

Tags: cron

Can you tell me expression for magento cron schedule to run script every 4 hours - every day. I tried:

```
<schedule><cron_expr>0 */4 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

But job is not showing in cron_schedule table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * *`

Note, if you do not see the cron in the table, it's not an error, because the scheduler creates the record with some delay.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 */4 * * *
```

change to

```
25 */4 * * *
```

this code means cron job will run at 12.00, 1.00 and so on.
if you want changed to time  12.30 ,1.30  and so  on then  change to 0 to 30

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374844/run-an-magento-function-cron-at-every-hour

Comment: This is for every hour, I need for every 4 hours

Comment: ok ,i  will give you .....