# How to set cron every seven days?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, cron

I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <send_customer_emails>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 */7 * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>emailmodel/observer::sendEmails</model>
            </run>
        </send_customer_emails>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

I have checked when I use below expression, it works.

```
* * * * *
```

Is it a magento bug? Or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: your cronjob code is perfect, may be having some issue with code. you can simply check by adding log in your
"sendEmails" function in "emailmodel/observer"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule cron job every four hours](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32393/schedule-cron-job-every-four-hours)

Comment: The cron expression is not "perfect", it matches every day that's divisible by 7, i.e. the 7th of the month, the 14th, the 21th and the 28th. The answers, suggesting a cron expression for "once a week on weekday X" are therefore correct

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
//this will run every saturday midnight
<schedule>
     <cron_expr>0 0 * * 6</cron_expr>
</schedule>

* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That should do it:

```
5 8 * * 6 <user> <command>
```

or for readability

```
5 8 * * Sat <user> <command>
```

documentation (man 5 crontab):

```
          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Sat 8:05AM run find

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    5       8          *             *                Sat              /usr/bin/fi
```

**Set up cron in Magento**

In the Magento admin, go to: System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks) and configure cron jobs you wish to run.

You should know that Magento runs cron jobs even if you don't have a daily cron job configured. Whenever Magento receives a request, it checks if there are any cron jobs to be run. Therefore, having the daily cron job would only make sense if you had no requests for an entire day.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Your cron explanation is for Linux, not for the Magento cron system, although there is much similarity.